# silky smooth scrolling on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

I am using animate.

Please click the loadmore button that appears at the bottom:http://www.arrowlife.com

I personally feel that scroll up animation is a little jerky.

I want to give it a very smooth butter like feeling(like we have on iphone).How could I do some ultra smooth animtion(if possible with jquery,avoiding any plugin.)

I tried linear,swing..but dint get the desired result.I viewd a few SO links but was not satisfied.

```
var scroll=$(document).scrollTop()+700;
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop:scroll
    }, 1200);
```

Comment: Smooth scrolling on iOS is related to a close tie between hardware and software - talking directly to the graphics processor. Achieving the same thing in software only requires extremely fast hardware, is my guess.

Comment: @Floris:yes,but if not exactly like that we can get a little closer atleast..

Comment: its right at the bottom..scroll first!!!

Comment: @Onaseriousnote the page you posted does not have the button.. the homepage does..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - thanks. I see it now. Very smooth for me. Could it be a question of processor speed / bandwidth?

Comment: I dunno, its viewing in my browser...i dunno wats the problem...updated the link!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll = $(document).scrollTop() + 700;
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: scroll
}, 1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
```

I think the effect you are looking for is called easing, if I understand you correct. I prefer "easeInOutQuart", but check out all of the jQuery UI easings. Hope this helps!

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html